# Customize Issue UI

Tags: issue-tracking, youtrack

Is there a way to change the issue UI as it's possible to change notifications template?

I saw a category called **Template components** where I can customize templates very similar to issue UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### YouTrack UI Customizing in similar way as Notification templates?

No, unfortunatelly, some coding is needed to get an alternative UI, as far as I know.

### YouTrack UI Customizing in general?

Yes. However, you need to create your own web page and use *YouTrack REST API* to get data from YouTrack server.

Here are some links that might help you:

- [YouTrack REST API](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD6/YouTrack+REST+API+Reference)
- [Nice introduction article with an example](http://blog.jetbrains.com/youtrack/2012/09/creating-an-alternative-ui-for-youtrack/)